# Using jQuery and external javascript libraries using jQuery inside of AngularJS Routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-ng-route

So I want to create a SPA (single page application) using AngularJS' Routing with ng-route. The thing is that a few of the html pages use jQuery or load external JS files containing jQuery (libraries and plugins I want to include), and I also have a few pages that use angularJs.

When I tried moving the website to a SPA using AngularJS' ng-route the problem that occured was that visually it appeared the pages load fine, but the thing is the external scripts and the code using jQuery I wrote don't appear to work.

So my question is separated into two;
1. How can I fix this so that the application using ng-route would load the scripts and be able to run jQuery inside the AngularJS app?
2. I don't mind writing the routing part of the application with another framework/library or whatever. Are there any technologies that would support some pages running jQuery and some pages running AngularJS?

Thanks in advance.